# Workflow in ArcGIS Pro for WGS84 EMG2008 to NAVD88 Elevations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, vertical-transformation

Can someone walk me through their workflow to obtain NAVD88 elevations in ArcGIS Pro starting with WGS84 elevations (EGM2008 ellipsoid for heights)?

It would have to be something like the below, but what specific tools are suited to the job?

A) Convert WGS84 elevations to ellipsoid heights using the EGM2008 model.

B) Convert from WGS84 to NAD83 (US feet) using transformation.

C) Convert from NAD83 to NAVD88 by either GEOID12B or GEOID18.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Project tool. You need to install the ArcGIS Coordinate System Data setup that corresponds to your ArcGIS Desktop version. GEOID18 just got added to the upcoming, ArcGIS 10.8.1 (and ArcGIS Pro 2.6).

Comment: Where can the System Data be downloaded from? Thanks. I was under the impression that "Project" only did horizontal coordinate systems.

Comment: It'll depend on what version you have. There's a checkbox labeled vertical. Get CS from myesri or ask whoever can download the sw to get it for you.